# Null Value in Date field of Data Frame, how to skip it to format as date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, null

I have a DataFrame which have date fields, some of which are containing None values.

I am changing  all the dates which are in milliseconds to ddmmyyyy using below but facing issue when the value is None

```
 dataframe['dt'] =dataframe['dt']/1000.0
        dataframe['dt']=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dataframe['dt']).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Tried to disregard the None Values as below, but it is not executing the condition and going directly to else

```
 dataframe['dt']=np.where(dataframe['dt']==pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan,dataframe['dt']/1000)
        dataframe['dt']=np.where(dataframe['dt']==pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dataframe['dt']).strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

It is becoming tiring now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `apply`:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'dt':[1564025326921, 1564025327921, None, 1564025328921]})
df['dt'] =df['dt']/1000.0
df['dt']= df['dt'].apply(lambda t: None if np.isnan(t) else datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t).strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
df.head(10)
```

This will output:

```
    dt
0   24/07/2019
1   24/07/2019
2   None
3   24/07/2019
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
pd.to_datetime(dataframe['dt'], unit='ms', format='%d%m%Y', errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inbuilt method in pandas `pd.to_datetime` to covert value as DateTime objects. once you convert to Datetime you can change the format more flexibly.
If you want to convert the column 'date' to Datetime object, you can do it as below
`df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%d/%m/%y', errors='coerce')`

`errors='coerce` will make non convertible items as NaT